# How do I combine two objects based off unique similarities in key names?

Tags: javascript

I have two objects, each with four keys in a React Component. One of the object's keys contain character values and the other contains integers. I want to display them both inside a JSX tag by descending order according to the numerical object's key values.

The hard part is when I then want to have the corresponding character object keys next to the numerical ones. My problem is both objects keys start off indexed in the proper order, when I sort the numerical one, I don't know how to shuffle the character one the same way so they stay synced up.

The two objects are pulled from states that I have in my constructor, each of the different points states equals a number. Each of the player states equals a name, my intention is to display "playerx: pointsx  points" in descending order by points.

```
all.points = {{this.state.points1},{this.state.points2},{this.state.points3},{this.state.points4}}

all.players = {{this.state.player1},{this.state.player2},{this.state.player3},{this.state.player4}}
```

Desired Output Example (with plugged in values):

```
let: player1: Roger
     player2: Steve
     player3: Mark
     player4: Pamela

and let: points1: 4
         points2: 6
         points3: 2
         points4: 5
<div>
Steve: 6 points
Pamela: 5 points
Roger: 4 points
Mark: 2 points
</div>
```

In short, each of these names and points values are individual states, and I want `this.state.playerx` linked up to `this.state.pointsx` while in descending order of points.

Comment: I see nothing but syntax errors here; or did you use the wrong tags? Which language is this?

Comment: JSX, in my example I used the word let but didn't mean it in the creating a variable sense, probably could've picked something less confusing. I also forgot to wrap whats in the div tags in squiggly brackets.  I didn't really write any code just sort of posting the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a single array which contains objects with the players' name and points and then sort that array based on the players' points, here is an example:

```js
const names = {
  player1: 'Roger',
  player2: 'Steve',
  player3: 'Mark',
  player4: 'Pamela'
}

const points = {
  points1: 4,
  points2: 6,
  points3: 2,
  points4: 5
}

const players = Object.entries(names).reduce((a, [key, value]) => {
  const nr = key.replace(/\D/g, '');
  a.push({
    name: value,
    points: points[`points${nr}`]
  });
  return a;
}, []);

players.sort(({points: a}, {points: b}) => b - a);

console.log(players);
```

And the JSX will look like this:

```
<div>
  {players.map((player) => (<div>{player.name}: {player.points}</div>))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to have an array of objects instead of an object of objects. here is a react example that has an array of objects with the signature {name: string, points: number"

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-dytig?fontsize=14